# Differences between org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender and org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender

Tags: log4j, rollingfileappender, extras

Can someone tell what are different between this things? Moreover, I can't understand, why needs use TimeBasedRollingPolicy if DailyRollingFileAppender exists ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender** is used to roll files when they reach a defined size.

**org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender** is a more generic and configurable rolling appender that allows for different rolling and triggering policies.

From the **org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender** [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html):

> RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files when
> they reach a certain size. The log4j extras companion includes
> alternatives which should be considered for new deployments and which
> are discussed in the documentation for
> org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender.

And the **org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender** [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html):

> RollingFileAppender extends FileAppender to backup the log files
> depending on RollingPolicy and TriggeringPolicy.

Comment: Can I use both types of Appenders in my log4j.xml?

Answer (score 2):

The URL has changed and is now: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html